# Adding the localizing pin in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I understood that, in order to visualize an attraction or a commercial venue in Google Maps you use Maps JavaScript API. However this would be for maps that would be displayed on websites or mobile devices only?

How would it be possible to map and localize a feature in Google Maps, as these are accessed from Google website? I mean, is it possible to map and visualize something that would be accessible and visible to anyone opening Google Maps? A special request should be made to Google?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This website is for asking questions about programming. Also your question is not very clear. If you are asking on how to add a missing place on Google Maps, please check [this link](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6320846?hl=en). If you want to add your own business as a Google Place, please visit [Google My Business website](https://www.google.com/business/). Once the place is approved and added by Google, it will be available on Google Maps website and mobile apps as well as through Google's various APIs and web services.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your reply. It was exactly what I was looking for. I have another question though. Would it be possible to add a whole trail on Google Maps? For example adding some castles that are missing on Google Maps, as several missing places but also the historical trail that connects them? This would have a great interest for tourism development purposes. Thanks a lot.  Stefano

Comment: You can add missing roads as well if that's what you refer to by "trail", have a look at https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088.

Comment: MrUpsidown thanks a lot! I have now all the info I needed for my research. Thanks again.  Stefano